# Can see DesignerView in UWP VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have Visual Studio 2015. Just created empty UWP project. When I do click on MainPage.xaml it normally should show design view. It just shows XAML code. When I right click on MainPage.xaml and then ViewDesiger xaml code became focus again.

Did anyhone had smiliar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, you need to be sure you have installed the correct version of the Windows Universal SDK 
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Please be sure you have installed the last  version of Visual Studio 2015 it must be Update 1
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx